# Define fontsize for the legend text of every subplot of pandas figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have multiple dataframes for each of which I plot the performance metrics.
Each dataframe looks like (the number of columns is different in every df):

```
    index,jack,steve,bob,sandra,helen,tracy
    1,300,100,110,500,120,100
    2,30,20,150,200,10,120
    3,320,110,190,50,12,130
    4,300,100,110,500,120,100 
    5,400,120,100,450,100,90
```

I want to plot each of the columns on the separate subplot of the same figure and save it in the png file.

I can't find how I can change the fontsize of the legend (the names of the students in the given example), when I'm using the following snippet with `plt.legend` only the last legend size is updated, but not every one of the subplot's legends.

```
def plot_subplot(df, group):
    ax = df.plot(subplots=True, fontsize=20, figsize=(80,40))
    plt.legend(loc='best', prop={'size': 30})
    ax[0].get_figure().savefig("{}.png".format(group), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
```

Because the number of columns in each dataframe is different, I don't know in advance the number of subplots the function will produce for a given plot. I'm using the `subplots=True` parameter and not defining manually the position of each subplot via ax1, ax2 etc. That's why I'm looking for a solution compatible with this use case.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `df.plot` currently returns a *list* of `Axes` (due to `subplots=True`), so you should iterate `ax`:

```
def plot_subplot(df, group):
    ax = df.plot(subplots=True, fontsize=20, figsize=(80, 40))
    
    # iterate all Axes
    for a in ax:
        a.legend(loc='best', prop={'size': 30})
    
    ax[0].get_figure().savefig('{}.png'.format(group), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
```

[image]